# get multiple random values from ArrayList HashMap

Tags: java, random, arraylist, hashmap

I want to get some specific number random values from ArrayList

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for (int i = 0; i == 4; i++) {

        index = random.nextInt(menuItems.size());
        HashMap<String, String> getitem = menuItems.get(index);
        System.out.println(getitem.get(KEY_NAME));
    }
```

Nothing is printing out.

Code in loop works if i use it outside loop, but since i need multiple values, i use loop and it doesnt work.

Comment: Thought about using a debugger or old style '*printf debugging*'?

Comment: Style note but it's a good idea to code to interfaces where possible: `final List<Map<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
for (int i = 0; i == 4; i++) { // start with i beeing 0, execute while i is 4
                               // never true
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  // start with i beeing 0, execute while i is
                               // smaller than 4, true 4 times
```

### Explanation:

A for loop has the following structure:

```
for (initialization; condition; update)
```

`initialization` is executed once before the loop starts. `condition` is checked before each iteration of the loop and `update` is executed after every iteration.

Your initialization was `int i = 0;` (executed once). Your condition was `i == 4`, which is false, because `i` is `0`. So the condition is false, and the loop is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

The ending condition of your for loop is broken: `for (int i = 0; i == 4; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` (4 iterations) or `for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)` (5 iterations).

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) explains how the `for` statement works.